# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable / GAN network error

Tags: gradient, valueerror, generative-adversarial-network

I have generators and discriminators to run as part of a GAN network. on text data. Although it seems that they work fine in terms of generating synthetic data and discriminator's loss. but I get this error when running them within the network. so I tested them separately and I get a gradient NONE for the generator: I am not sure how to go about it. appreciate replies and help. the network is similar to that of privGAN on GitHub.

Here is the generator

```
class Generator(Model):
    def __init__(self, num_emb, emb_dim, hidden_dim, sequence_length, 
       learning_rate, grad_clip, num_lstm, dropout_rate, batch_size):
        super().__init__()

        self.num_emb = num_emb
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.grad_clip = grad_clip
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.embedding = layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.num_emb, 
         output_dim=emb_dim)
        self.lstms = [layers.LSTM(hidden_dim, return_sequences=True, 
        dropout=dropout_rate) for _ in range(num_lstm)]
        #self.lstm = layers.LSTM(hidden_dim,return_sequences=False, 
         return_state=True, dropout=dropout_rate)
        self.dense = layers.Dense(self.num_emb)

        self.optimizer = Adam(self.learning_rate, 
        clipnorm=self.grad_clip)
        self.loss_fn = 
       
      tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
        self.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss=self.loss_fn)


    def call(self, start_tokens, temperature=1.0, training=False):

        generated_sequences = start_tokens  # initialize with start 
         tokens
        x = self.embedding(start_tokens[:, 0:1])

        for i in range(1, self.sequence_length):
            for lstm in self.lstms:
                x = lstm(x,training=training)


            logits = self.dense(x)
            current_logits = logits[:, -1, :]
            logits_exp = tf.math.exp(current_logits / temperature)
            sum_exp = tf.reduce_sum(logits_exp, axis=1, 
            keepdims=True)
            probs = logits_exp / sum_exp

            next_tokens = tf.random.categorical(probs, 1)

            # Concatenate new tokens to the generated sequence
            generated_sequences = tf.concat([generated_sequences, 
            next_tokens], axis=1)

            # Embed the next_tokens for the next LSTM computation
            x = self.embedding(next_tokens)

        return generated_sequences
```

running below code

```
#Compute gradients
gen_gradients = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator1.trainable_weights)
disc_gradients = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator1.trainable_weights)

# Print gradients
for model, grads in zip(['Generator', 'Discriminator'], [gen_gradients, disc_gradients]):
    print(f"\n{model} Gradients:")
    for grad, var in zip(grads, generator1.trainable_weights if model=='Generator' else discriminator1.trainable_weights):
        print(f"{var.name}: {grad}")
```

*outputs:*

Generator Gradients:
generator/embedding/embeddings:0: None
generator/lstm/lstm_cell/kernel:0: None
generator/lstm/lstm_cell/recurrent_kernel:0: None
generator/lstm/lstm_cell/bias:0: None
generator/lstm_1/lstm_cell_1/kernel:0: None
generator/lstm_1/lstm_cell_1/recurrent_kernel:0: None
generator/lstm_1/lstm_cell_1/bias:0: None
generator/lstm_2/lstm_cell_2/kernel:0: None
generator/lstm_2/lstm_cell_2/recurrent_kernel:0: None
generator/lstm_2/lstm_cell_2/bias:0: None
generator/lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/kernel:0: None
generator/lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/recurrent_kernel:0: None
generator/lstm_3/lstm_cell_3/bias:0: None
generator/dense/kernel:0: None
generator/dense/bias:0: None